# Где полную документацию по библиотеке mailru-im-bot

Tags: python, бот, icq

Mailru-im-bot если вы знаете icq то библиотека по созданию ботов icq на основе python. Документация на официальном сайте не даёт полную информацию по этой библиотеке.

Просьба если у вас есть вот полное описание этой библиотеки, то пожалуйста дайте ссылку

Comment: Документация - https://icq.com/botapi/#/messages/get_messages_editText github - https://github.com/mail-ru-im/bot-python

Comment: Когда я писал бота на icq я черпал инфу именно из исходников, вы нигде не найдете подробности по написанию ботов под icq. В любом случае, начните с простого echo бота, будут трудности задавайте вопросы на so, я постараюсь помочь.

Comment: и между прочим, на офф сайте достаточно полная информация. хех, все что вам нужно для старта там есть

Comment: Смотрите чтобы разобраться во всем я скачал даже исходник и попробовал разобраться
Но там некоторые вещи я не понял
В методе класса Bot send_file есть параметр file_id вот что это такое
Я хотел бы узнать как пользоваться всеми методами и все остальное

Comment: Качать его не нужно, смысла нет. В исходниках так же есть папка example там вроде ещё понятнее....

Comment: В чем конкретно сложность? Вас никто не ведёт за руку?